# Question about the phonemes /ŋ/ and /ɲ/

Tags: phonétique

I have some questions regarding the phonemes /ŋ/ and /ɲ/ and hope you can help me. In *The Pronunciation of Canadian French*, Douglas Walker says (this applies to standard French):

> It is not uncommon to hear /b d g/ realized as
>   /m n ŋ/ when the stops are adjacent to nasals.

Then he gives the following examples:

> admirer [anmirer]
>
> une longue minute [ynlɔ̃ŋminyt]
>
> diagnostique [diaŋnɔstik]
>
> la grande dame [lagrɑ̃ndam]
>
> ça tombe mal [satɔ̃mmal]
>
> il est completement dingue, mon ami [...dɛ̃ŋmɔ̃nami]
>
> la bombe [labɔm]

My first question is: does this mean that in standard, proper French you should not pronounce these nasals consonants /m n ŋ/ but rather /b d g/ in these examples?

My second question is about the phoneme /ɲ/:

> There is an interesting process at work whereby /ɲ/ has a
>   tendency to be realized as /nj/:
>
> panier [panje]
>
> union [ynjɔ̃]
>
> versus
>
> baigner **[bɛnje] < /bɛɲe/**
>
> accompagner **[akɔ̃panje] < /akɔ̃paɲe/**
>
> brugnon **[brynjɔ̃] < /bryɲɔ̃/**

Does */ɲ/ has a
tendency to be realized as /nj/* mean that in proper French you should say [paɲe] and [yɲɔ̃]? And how are these two examples opposed to baigner, accompagner and brugnon? I don't understand the bolded notation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this mean that in standard, proper French you should not pronounce these nasals consonants /m n ŋ/ but rather /b d g/ in these examples?

You’re exactly right. They should be pronounced [b d g] in standard proper French. Thus, in spoken Canadian French, it is “not uncommon” *(by no means generalized throughout)* to hear:

- *admirer* as [anmire]
      (where the standard would be /admiʁe/)
- *une longue minute* as [yn.lɔ̃ŋ.mi.nyt]
      (instead of /yn.lɔ̃ɡ.mi.nyt/)
- *diagnostique* as [diaŋnɔstik]
      (instead of /diaɡnɔstik/)
- *la grande dame* as [la.grɑ̃n.dam]
      (instead of /la.grɑ̃d(ə).dam/)
- *ça tombe mal* as [sa.tɔ̃m.mal]
      (instead of /sa.tɔ̃b.mal/)
- *il est complètement dingue, mon ami* as [...dɛ̃ŋ.mɔ̃.na.mi]
      (instead of /...dɛ̃ɡ.mɔ̃.na.mi/)
- *la bombe* as [la.bɔ̃m]
      (instead of /la.bɔ̃b/)

> Does /ɲ/ has a tendency to be realized as /nj/ mean that in proper French you should say [paɲe] and [yɲɔ̃]?

No that’s not the case. PANIER and UNION are both properly and commonly realized as [nj]. They appear to be examples for the words that follow them, that should be realized [ɲ], but are rather commonly realized as [nj] in Canadian French (and in French in general these days, actually).

I did not understand the “**<**” sign in the citation at first either, but [thanks to @jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32595/question-about-the-phonemes-%c5%8b-and-%c9%b2#comment66883_32600), there is a plausible explanation now, that is, the realization [nj] came from the theoretical phonologic /ɲ. Either way, the proper pronunciations for BAIGNER, ACCOMPAGNER & BRUGNON all use [ɲ], and the process “currently at work” in spoken Canadian French is turning them into [nj] instead.

Comment: I believe the `<`sign just tells the actual phonetic **[nj]** comes from the theoretical phonologic **/ɲ/**.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Just one more question: can you hear [anmirer],  [ynlɔ̃ŋminyt],  [diaŋnɔstik] etc. in European French too?

Comment: @lmc it's the usual realisation of all those words, yeah. The only one of your list that's rarer and strongly stigmatised is bombe pronounced as [bõ:m] when not followed by a consonant.

Answer (score -6):

cas 1 et 3. Non, cela semble complètement faux en ce qui concerne le premier cas et le troisième; ces prononciation ne peuvent pas être standard; voilà la prononciation de « diagnostique » :  [djaɡnɔstik]. On la trouve dans le TLFi, dans d'autre [sources](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/diagnostique); je n'ai jamais entendu  « [diaŋnɔstik] » et ne l'ai jamais utilisée moi-même.

cas 2. Pour le second il se peut qu'il y ait cette tendance, mais ce ne peut être que vérifiable dans les accents qui laissent tomber les e finaux, l'accent parisien et l'accent du Nord.

cas 4. la grande dame [lagrɑ̃ndam]. Lorsque l'accent ne laisse pas tomber le e final cela n'est pas possible et comme un accent standard pour le français est un tel accent, l'auteur doit extrapoler quelque peu; néanmoins, pour un accent tel que l'accent parisien il existe une façon de prononcer ces consonnes doubles (puisque le e disparait) qui est similaire à la prononciation de ces combinaisons en anglais, lesquelles sont appelées « geminates » dans la phonétique de cette langue; en ce qui concerne au moins l'accent parisien ces combinaisons de mots sont prononcées avec un long /d/, c'est à dire qu'un stop est initié sur le d de « grande », maintenu un peu plus longtemps que pour une plosive normale puis relâché sur le d de dame (autre exemple : code direct ).

cas 5. ça tombe mal [satɔ̃mmal]. Dans les accents sans e, il est possible que cette tendance soit assez forte; personnellement, je ne vois pas comment prononcer ces deux bilabiales d'affilé proprement d'une autre façon.

cas 6. il est completement dingue, mon ami [...dɛ̃ŋmɔ̃nami]. Même relativement aux accents sans e, cela ne peut s'entendre que chez des personnes dont la prononciation est relâchée ; chez le locuteur avec une bonne articulation on entend distinctement le son /g/.

cas 7. la bombe [labɔm]. Cette prononciation n'est pas standard ; il faut l'admettre, sans l'appui d'une voyelle initiale dans le mot qui suit (bombe atomique) ce /b/ est difficile à placer; cependant il s'entend clairement d'habitude, par exemple dans cette prononciation proposée par [reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/bombe/forced).

Question 2

Non,  pour « panier » on ne doit pas dire « pagne é » plutôt que « pas niais ». Il en est de même pour « union ».

Les prononciations pour « baigner », « accompagner » et « brugnon » continuent à être  « /bɛɲe/ », « /akɔ̃paɲe/ » et 
« /bryɲɔ̃/ »; cependant il existe une certaine tendance de changement pour une prononciation avec /n/.

Par exemple « brugnon » doit avoir la prononciation « [[bʁyɲɔ̃]](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/brugnon) ».

Il semble qu'il faille prendre l'opposition comme étant dans la réalisation du n qui est normalement /n/ pour le deux premiers et /ɲ/ pour les autres.

La notation en gras doit signifier que les deux prononciations sont utilisées et que celle qui est la norme est à droite du signe; je ne crois que cela soit autre chose; il faudrait vérifier dans l'ouvrage la liste des symboles utilisés.

Comment: *The Pronunciation of Canadian French*... What else can one say to someone who can't tell the difference between descriptive and prescriptive?